# UIActivityViewController - Detecting error in sending vs. cancel

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Currently I'm using the following code to instantiate a UIActivityViewController:

```
NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:bodyMessage, nil];
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, nil];
        [activityVC setValue:subject forKey:@"subject"];
        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];


        [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL done)
         {

             NSString *ServiceType;
             if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail] )           ServiceType = @"Mail.";
             if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage] )  ServiceType = @"Messenger.";

             NSMutableString *shareWithActivityResultMessage;
             NSString *alertTitle;
             if (done)
             {
                 alertTitle = @"Success!";

                 shareWithActivityResultMessage = [NSMutableString stringWithString:successMessage];
                 [shareWithActivityResultMessage appendString:ServiceType];
             }
             else
             {
                 // didn't succeed.
                 alertTitle = @"Error";
                 shareWithActivityResultMessage = [NSMutableString stringWithString:errorMessage];
             }
```

When I cancel composing, the ActivityVC `done = false` and thus the error message is triggered. Is there a way to detect canceling as opposed to an actual error in sending the message?

Comment: The docs clearly state that the completion handler is called even if the user cancels. And in this case `done` will be `NO`. This does not indicate an error. You should not show an error alert just because `done` is `NO`. In fact, the `UIActivityViewController` gives no indication of an error of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

You can using the new UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler type in iOS 8:

```
activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError){
    ...
}
```

Just check the activityError property